# Pyephem - Degree position of planets

Tags: pyephem

Done some searching and can't find a direct answer (well, one that i can understand!)

I want to compute the degree (out of 360 degrees) that the planets (Sun through to Pluto) are at a given time and location. I have the below code. I want to compute Zero degrees as the ascendent and progress from there.

pic of chart for date, time, location.  AS = 0 Degrees, Jup = circa 43 degrees, Sat = circa 93 degrees, etc...
[Astro Chart for Date, Time & Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XPfb.png)

Many thanks, Will

```
>>> from ephem import *
>>> sun = Sun()
>>> moo = Moon()
>>> mer = Mercury()
>>> mar = Mars()
>>> ven = Venus()
>>> jup = Jupiter()
>>> sat = Saturn()
>>> plu = Pluto()
>>> northwich = Observer()
>>> northwich.lat = '53.15'
>>> northwich.lon = '02.31'
>>> northwich.elevation = 36
>>> northwich.date = '2018/7/30 10:56'
>>> sun.compute(northwich)
>>> moo.compute(northwich)
>>> mer.compute(northwich)
>>> mar.compute(northwich)
>>> ven.compute(northwich)
>>> jup.compute(northwich)
>>> sat.compute(northwich)
>>> plu.compute(northwich)
>>> print(sun.alt, sun.az, moo.alt, moo.az... etc
```

Comment: What is "the ascendent"? If you could figure out where it is along the 360°, then simple subtraction might give you the values for the planets.

Comment: Hi Brandon, the ascendent in astrology is the the value of the ecliptical geocentric longitude which is easterly on the horizon which refers to zero degrees... would this be eqv. to Ecliptic.lon?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "easterly on the horizon which refers to zero degrees" but that does sound like ecliptic longitude. You could try printing out some ecliptic longitudes and compare the values to those given for "the ascendent".

Comment: Hi Brandon, still plugging away at this! The Ascendent is basically the easterly horizon. So at dawn the sun will be at 0 degrees and will set at 180 degrees and rise again at 0 degrees during a 24 hour period... is that any clearer?!@*!

Comment: If that's the case, maybe you could generate a pair of those charts for, say, 1 hour apart. If the degrees are indeed measured from the horizon, then two charts 1 hour apart should show each planet having moved 15° since that is about how far the sky moves in 1 hour — it would be a quick way to determine whether those angles really start at the horizon.